# How to redirect in JavaScript to another website after establishing an authenticated session using PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

## SOLVED

##### The title wasn't enough for the question, I'll elaborate here.

### The Problem

I have two systems lets call them **`system A`** and **`system B`**. **`System A`** is a Petite-vue/Codeigniter stack. **`System B`** could be a Codeigniter or Laravel back-end (front-end could vary).
Here is a graph showing the setup (**`R1`** and **`R2`** will be explained below).

> **NOTE:** In the graph below **`R2`** is sent from the back-end to **`system B`**.

[image: Systems layout]

In **`system A`**, I am making an asynchronous Fetch request, lets call this request **`R1`**, from the JavaScript (petite-vue) code to the PHP (Codeigniter), which is in the same system (it being **`system A`**). (Code below)

```js
      function Connect_To_System(url){
        fetch("<?= base_url("connect") ?>",
                {
                  method: "POST",
                  body: JSON.stringify( {URL: url} )
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                  // do something with response data like showing a message
                }) 
      }
```

**`R1`** is handled in the PHP (Codeigniter) code, which establishes an authenticated session with **`system B`** by sending a cURL request, lets call this request **`R2`**, to **`system B`**. After **`R2`** response returns an HTTP 200 status, I want to redirect the user from **`system A`** to **`system B`** in a new tab. (Code below, note that I'm using REST_Controller)

```php
    public function connect_post(){
        $data = json_decode($this->post()[0]);
        $url = $data->URL;
        $url_login = $url.'/auth/login';
        $token = $this->session->tempdata('token');
        $username = $this->current_user['emp_no'];
        $digest = md5($username.$token);

        $params= array(
            "username" => $username,
            "token" => $token
        );
        $result = $this->postCURL($url_login, $params);
        // Redirect in a new tab when status is 200 somehow
        // Return a response to the JavaScript
    }
```

The problem is that I can't redirect the user to another page from the PHP (Codeigniter), because it was called by **`R1`**. Thus, I must redirect the user from the View that made R1 using JavaScript.

However, the solution to first problem doesn't work because the session that was established by **`R2`** is tied to PHP (Codeigniter), or cURL I can't really tell, in other words it's the server that established the session not the user. And redirecting the user using JavaScript will tie the redirection to the user, or whatever the redirect method is.

### Possible Solution (Not Preferred `EDIT: It is preferred`)

The only functional solution is to establish the session with **`system B`** from the JavaScript and then redirect the user, which is what I'm currently doing. But the problem is that I'm exposing the authentication data to whom ever simply decides to open the browser inspect. That's why I'm trying to keep all the important data in the back-end PHP code.

### The Main Goal

All I want is a way to keep the authentication data hidden, whatever the method may be, if that's possible really.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you send authentication data to system A, then system A request to system B, so why don't you just send the authentication to system B? They are the same thing

Comment: @Canh I don't think I understood you correctly, but here what I think. In R1, I am technically telling the back-end to send the authentication data that it has stored in it to the URL I provided in the R1 request. Then my back-end is sending via R2 request the authentication data that is stored in it to the provided URL which leads to system B. If you're asking why I'm not sending the authentication data straight from the front-end to system B, then I made it clear that it is what I am doing right now. I know if I don't do R1 asynchronously then problem is solved but I want it to be that way.

Comment: I got it. Sorry for the first comment. But I think that if you want to hide authentication data, you can do like this: instead of requesting from users to system B after R2 success, you should change all the requests to B from the users you need to system A. Now, all requests come to system A only, then A will interact with system B. You don't need to worry about the redirect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the proposed solution in the question actually is preferred. Since the token of the user is so personalized and it is even stored in the server session and stored in the database, it would so difficult to authenticate you're self using someone else's authentication data. Thus, there is no major security vulnerability. The idea of exposed data scared me that it blinded me from seeing that exposing the token isn't a huge security vulnerability.